# Is this the right way for interacting with a smart contract?

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts

I'm trying to call `claimItem` function on my ERC721 token. This function basically calls `_safeMint()` function from `OpenZeppelin ERC721` contract. Here is the question. As a first step I managed deploy a contract on polygon mumbai testnet and I can see my contract on polygon scan. But when I tried to call `claimItem` function, inside a Transaciton `Transaction(from:EthereumAddress.fromHex(session!.accounts[0]) ,to:EthereumAddress.fromHex("CONTRACT_ADDRESS"), data: bytes);` like this. Transaction completes but NFT is not minted.

Here Are Some Scree Shots

This one is from a successful one (This is deployed and minted with truffle & web3)
[image]

This one is from unsuccessful one (This is signed by MetaMask)
[image]

I don't know what I'm doing wrong and I'm really new into blockchain.

EDIT Contract

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.4;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/Counters.sol";

contract ArtItemNew is ERC721, Ownable {    
    using Counters for Counters.Counter;
    Counters.Counter private _tokenIds;
    using Strings for uint256;
    // Optional mapping for token URIs
    mapping(uint256 => string) private _tokenURIs;

    
    
    

    constructor(string memory _tokenName, string memory _tokenSymbol) ERC721(_tokenName, _tokenSymbol) public {


    }

    function _setTokenURI(uint256 tokenId, string memory _tokenURI)
        internal
        virtual
    {
        require(
            _exists(tokenId),
            "ERC721Metadata: URI set of nonexistent token"
        );
        _tokenURIs[tokenId] = _tokenURI;
    }

    function claimItem(string memory tokenURI) public returns (uint256) {
        _tokenIds.increment();
        uint256 newItemId = _tokenIds.current();
        _mint(msg.sender, newItemId);
        _setTokenURI(newItemId, tokenURI);
        return newItemId;
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to provide more info and code for the claimItem function.

If I look at the 2nd screenshot, it looks like the transaction went through, but the transfer didn't happen (_safeMint should transfer from zero address to 'to' address)

Comment: I'm trying to make this interaction with flutter walletconnect_dart package I added the contract. Basically I'm sending request to MetaMask mobile app to sign this transaction.

Comment: Actually MetaMask doesnt sees my transaction as contract interaction.